# Dynamic routing in ember shows the parent's model instead of its own

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple route from a list of colors to a single color. Unfortunately, once you navigate to `colors/:color`, ie `colors/red`, the model is not overridden property to the single model, and still reflects the color list.

How can I properly drill down to a single model?

Routes:

```
App.ColorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('color');
  }
});

App.ColorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.store.findBy("color", params.colors_id);
  }
});
```

Router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("colors", function(){
    this.resource("color", {path: "/:colors_id"});
  });
});
```

Issue reproduced in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sipexu/3/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things were not working for you-  I have a working jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/xejik/1

First, there is the undeclared "index" route under "colors".  Since you have that template, you should include an empty function in the map call:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("colors", function(){
    this.resource("color", {path: "/:colors_id"}, function() {});
  });
});
```

Also I changed the "color" template to display the color name.  Your `link-to` referenced `this`, rather than `item`:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    <li>{{#link-to "color" item}}{{item.color}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

You can read more about this (feature? issue?) here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/index-route-puzzle/5965

Comment: Great explanation, Thanks for linking me to your discussion on this issue.

Comment: Is it true, that every time I use a `resource` route, I must include an anonymous function?

Comment: It's definitely as intended.  The index route's best use is when you hit that resource and want to show a different view when that's as deep as you are versus when you go deeper.

Comment: Here's a fun example showing it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/884/edit or http://emberjs.jsbin.com/risezu/1/edit